# HTML in WordPress Title Displays Extra Characters

Tags: html, wordpress, title

I am trying to use an image as a header/title for a blog post in WordPress (the theme is my base 0.5 by mythem.es. I'm not sure if that's relevant though!).

The title section is recognizing the HTML that I type in (img src tags and the like) but when it is displayed on the page, there is a slight error. The image displays correctly but has a `">` directly above it. My HTML code in the header is as follows (I can't use the real HTML since this is for a client):

```
<center><img src="http://example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/example.jpg" alt="Example Blog | Example 2012" title="Example" width="525" height="60" /></center>
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this weird bit of code above my image?

Comment: are you adding this into the page body through wordpress backend gui? or are you actually editing the pure php/html for the page template?

Comment: I'm just inserting the HTML code into the title box (where the placeholder says "Enter title here) in the editor. For example, I click on "Add New" under the "Posts" section and then there's the empty title area.

Comment: can you post the outputted source of your header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't insert html to the title box because wordpress sanitize the title field when your save your post

Answer (score 0):

You can however use custom fields to use html in your WP title.

1. Create a custom field called HTML_title and add your html
2. Output custom field in your site:

`<?php $html_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, "HTML_title", true);`

`if ($html_title) { ?>`

```
  <h1><?php echo $html_title; ?></h1>`
```

`<?php } else { ?>`

```
 <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

`<?php } ?>`

Read full article here: http://digwp.com/2009/10/custom-fields-for-html-post-titles/